# How to access the first three values from a array of context variable in conditon node of watson conversation?

Tags: watson-conversation

I have an array of context passed to the conversation from the application. It is something like:
`result:[Apple,Orange,Mango,Grapes]`

1st instance- I want the first value of array
 `if context.result.length==3`
 I should get `[Apple,Orange,Mango]` and to get the output in response, I will use `$context.result[0],$context.result[1],$context.result[2]` which will give me `Apple`, `Orange`, `Mango`.

`if context.result.length==2`
 I should get `[Apple,Orange]` and to get the output in response `$context.result[0],$context.result[1]` which will give me `Apple`,`Orange`.

Can anyone tell me if this is the correct approach to access the context.

Comment: What is your question? What did you try? Anything that did not work?

Comment: Do you want output comma separated list of your `context.result`?

Comment: From my bot application - I'm sending a context array having  "results": ["Apple","Orange","Mango","Grapes"]. In my dialog I want to put a condition like if $results.length==2, then my response would be "We have $results[0],$results[1] in stock. I want my output to look like "We have Apple, Orange is stock". What would be the syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

In watson conversation you can use some methods with arrays. One of them is `join`

If you passing in the context all items which in stock and you want to have output like `We have X,Y,Z in stock`, then you can create output in Watson like this:

```
We have <? context.results.join(', ') ?> in stock
```

It will print all string values, which you have in context.results.

You can find more information about available methods in Watson conversation [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/dialog-methods.html#jsonarrayjoinstring-delimiter)

Comment: Thanks for this, but What will I put in condition node, wherein I want result as "We have <? context.results.join(', ') ?> in stock"

Comment: In conditions you can put `context.results != null`